# capitalized Words extracting using R

Tags: r, regex

```
ex03ProperNoun <- function(text) {
  assertString(text)
  words <- unique(grep('(?<![.!?]\\s)[A-Z][a-z0-9]+(?![.!?]\\s)', 
                       strsplit(text, ' ')[[1]], value = TRUE, perl = TRUE))
  words <- words[-1]
  index <- grep('\\.\\s?[A-Z][a-z0-9]+', text, perl = TRUE)[1]
  if (!is.na(index)) {
    words <- words[(-index)]  
  }
  return(words)
}

ex03ProperNoun("Proper Nouns are usually Capitalized.")
  # --> "Nouns"  "Capitalized"
  # my ouput: "Nouns"        "Capitalized."
ex03ProperNoun("proper nouns are usually Capitalized. This is, Proper for proper nouns.")
  # --> "Capitalized" "Proper"
  # my ouput: "Proper" 
ex03ProperNoun("The IBM5100 Portable Computer was one of the first portable computers.")
  # --> "IBM5100" "Portable" "Computer"
  # my ouput: "IBM5100"  "Portable" "Computer"
ex03ProperNoun("IBM5100 is the name of one of the first portable computers.")
  # --> character(0)
  # my ouput: character(0)
```

so my problem is that I keep getting the wrong outputs for some inputs. Why is that?

i tried to change the code but it still didnt work

Comment: `stringr::str_extract_all(text, "\\b(?!^)(?<![.?!]\\s{0,100})\\p{Lu}\\p{L}*\\b")`

Comment: Explain in the question what you need, what you have done and what is wrong. Else, it is a dead question.

Comment: Did it finally work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following base R solution:

```r
x <- c("Proper Nouns are usually Capitalized.",
    "proper nouns are usually Capitalized. This is, Proper for proper nouns.",
    "The IBM5100 Portable Computer was one of the first portable computers.",
    "IBM5100 is the name of one of the first portable computers.",
    "The IBM5100 Portable Computer was one of the first portable computers.")
 
regmatches(x, gregexpr("[?!.]\\s*\\w+(*SKIP)(*F)|\\b(?!^)\\p{Lu}\\w*\\b", x, perl=TRUE))
```

See the [R  demo](https://ideone.com/KevGfj) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cNSBMM/4).

**NOTE**: if you plan to use `stringr::str_extract_all` and you know there can be no more than 100 whitespaces between final sentence punctuation and the next word, you can also use `str_extract_all(x, "\\b(?!^)(?<![.?!]\\s{0,100})\\p{Lu}\\w*\\b")` since  ICU regex flavor allows constrained-width lookbehind patterns.

Output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Nouns"       "Capitalized"

[[2]]
[1] "Capitalized" "Proper"     

[[3]]
[1] "IBM5100"  "Portable" "Computer"

[[4]]
character(0)

[[5]]
[1] "IBM5100"  "Portable" "Computer"
```

PCRE regex details:

- `[?!.]\s*\w+(*SKIP)(*F)` - `?`, `!` or `.`, then zero or more whitespaces, one or more word chars and then the match is failed and the next match is searched for from the failure position
- `|` - or
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!^)` - not at the start of string
- `\p{Lu}` - an uppercase letter
- `\w*` - any zero or more word chars
- `\b` - a word boundary.

Comment: but ex03ProperNoun("The IBM5100 Portable Computer was one of the first portable computers.")
[1] "Portable" "Computer" should be "IBM5100" "Portable" "Computer" @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @tongtong Then replace all `\p{L}` with `\w`.

Comment: how do i change it so we have this result:                              text:
** [1] "A B, Y, A, P, B, Z, D, V, N, F, P, U, R, Z, Y, B, Y, E, R, E, T, Y, J, V, B, V, Y."

The expected result was:
 [1] "A" "B" "D" "E" "F" "J" "N" "P" "R" "T" "U" "V" "Y" "Z"
thank you so much btw

Comment: @tongtong No idea, this is out of the current question scope.